# ons-back-button prevent default click event

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

I have back-btn on a page called: 'page2.html' like this:

```
<ons-back-button id="back-btn-cat-page" onclick="back_emptyCart_alert();return false;"></ons-back-button>
```

And js function is:

```
function back_emptyCart_alert(){
    var page = sNavigator.getCurrentPage().page;
    alert('backtohome function starts: ')
    alert('page is: ');
    alert(page)
    if(page == "page2.html"){
        alert(page)
    }
}
```

Clicking back button will result in:
1. page is:
2. page1.html (not page2.html)!

Clicking the back button (not the button on the device) seems to trigger **after** the page is popped back **not before** that! Which makes it impossible to check, before deciding to move on.
How can I prevent default event of back button?

Comment: use jquery, it has preventDefault, which does not let button or link do anything.

Comment: Surprisingly, is doesn't work in this case!

Comment: please can you put a live page in jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: @ahmed Can I ask why are you using v1 instead of Onsen UI v2? https://onsen.io/v2/docs/guide/angular1/from-v1-to-v2.html

Comment: I started my project with v1 nothing else. Does v2 have an answer for this? and is it hard to move into v2?

Comment: @ahmed I actually added a link to the migration guide in the previous comment. v2 has many advantages over v1 so I don't see any reason to start projects with v1 anymore. And yes, it does have a solution, check the `onClick` property: https://onsen.io/v2/docs/js/ons-back-button.html#properties

Comment: Ok thanks, I will absolutely consider using v2.